# Why the value inside the loop and using the [i] is undefined?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

using Mozilla jetpack , when i do the following code .. i get that linking is undefined !!!  why ?   or how to fix it ?

```
var links = doc.querySelectorAll('#courses_menu > ul > li > a'); 
var linkz=links[1].href.split("?");

var i = 0;
for (i=0;i<=4;i++)
{
   var linking= links[i]; 
}
jetpack.notifications.show(" "+ linking);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it goes out of scope when the loop ends.

So you should have

```
var linking;
for (i=0;i<=4;i++)
{
   linking= links[i]; 
}
```

But furthermore, what are you trying to do here?  You overwrite linking four times.  Do you want to display all of the links?  If so, you can concatenate them like:

```
var linking = "";
for (i=0;i<=4;i++)
{
   linking = linking + links[i] + " "; 
}
```

Edit: the commenters are right; I did forget that there is no block scoping in Javascript.  Did this fix your code?  I can't imagine that it did.  The only other thing that I can think of is that `links[4]` is undefined, and then you would be assigning `undefined` to `linking`.

Anyway, I can't delete this because it's been accepted, but if anyone else comes up with a more useful answer, feel free to unaccept this one.

Comment: Thank youuu .. You are Right .. i can't believe this didn't cross my mind !

Comment: Not to my knowledge, or my spontaneous tests. Javascript maintins function scope, not block scope. Any variable declared inside a for loop will be accessible for the rest of the function until the function returns.

Comment: @seanmonster: If you declare it in or of the for loop (eg, `for(var i...`), it only exists in the for loop.

Comment: Um, no. Javascript only uses function scope. Try it: http://jsbin.com/uxaci3/edit